# Building rpm for gcc 4.8.2 rpath ERROR 0020:

Tags: gcc, rpmbuild

When building rpm's for centos I continue to get this error
ERROR   0020: file '/usr/local/probe/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0' contains an rpath referencing '..'

According to the docs I should be able to ignore this by calling:

`QA_RPATHS=$[ 0x0020 ] rpmbuild -v -bb --target=x86_64 ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/$PACKAGE.spec`

But it still gives me the same error.

the QA_RPATHS did solve the problem but our spec file was exporting a different QA_RPATH in the script. Once I removed that it was resolved.

Comment: Check your ~/.rpmmacros file and remove the line that says "check-rpaths" if it is there and try the rpmbuild.

Comment: That should work but is there a code I can exclude so that I don't ignore all error checking against rpaths?

Comment: Your question contains the code, but it is not working. Only other thing I can think of is to try adding /bin/env to your command:

/bin/env QA_RPATHS=$[ 0x0020 ] rpmbuild -v -bb --target=x86_64 ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/$PACKAGE.spec